# operator< overload for std::map's int type comparison? (I want it to sort in descending order..)

Tags: c++, stl

I have encountered a problem that I want to define a map, that is sorted internally by the first's descending order. if the first is not a primary type, like if it's a class, I can just overload the "<" within that class, but I don't know how to deal with the int type. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a comparator:

```
#include <functional>
map<int, value_type, greater<int>> m;
```

The default is `less<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a comparator when you create the map (it's an optional constructor argument).

e.g.:

```
bool my_compare(int x, int y) { return y < x; }

std::map<int,T,bool(*)(int,int)> my_map(my_compare);
```

Notice that I've needed to explicitly specify a 3rd template parameter as well.

[*Note: I would **strongly** advise that you don't overload the `<` operator to perform `>`...*]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the std::less implementation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/
You may write own comparator and use it together with map.